# Passing a report multiple values for a single parameter in SSRS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to pass in multiple values for a single parameter into a report running on SSRS.
The PHP code which fails with an Error, looks something like this:

```
$parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
$parameters[0]->Name = "lobtype";
$parameters[0]->Value = "property";

$parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
$parameters[1]->Name = "lobtype";
$parameters[1]->Value = "Casualty";

$rs->SetExecutionParameters2($parameters);
```

Found this discussion "'Allow Multiple Values' - Parameter" which has example PHP code, yet the Error passing in 2 Params with the same name, came up as though the required param "lobtype" was not even passed in.

Would you have any other examples as to how to get this work?